How to make sticky horizontal scrollbar for Tabulator?
I have tabulator with pagination for table usually used with page size of more rows than what fits on the screen so having sticky headers and horizontal scrollbar would be very useful.
The table has multiple thousands of rows so the pagination is used to somehow limit what is displayed, but some users also prefer to display more rows so they can scroll through some of the filtered data, but then they complain about not beeing able to scroll horizontally until they are at the very bottom of the page.
What is the common approach to solve this issue ?
Thanks in advance for any help
I tried to create separated custom sticky scrollbar but it breaks the headers as mentioned by Oli himself here:
https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/1051
I also tried the maxHeight option but this makes the whole thing completely unusable because of insanely long loading times.

I use 100vh for the height option in couple of my projects to make the table as tall as possible while keeping the sticky headers up top and horizontal scroll bar at the bottom of the page.  You can even try something like height: 'calc(100vh - 50px)' to give it a bit of space at the bottom.

Perfect, thank you ! I feel like an idiot that I didnt try that :D
